# I need to exclude twitter replies from my twitter feed

Tags: c#, twitter

Here is the code compliments of UmerPasha. It is returning tweets with replies. , but I got The code at UmerPasha blog. Thanks in advance. Im just including this paragraph so stack overflow will post.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

public string query = "";
//    public string url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json" ;
public string url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    findUserTwitter(url, query); //problem

}

public void findUserTwitter(string resource_url, string q)
{

    // oauth application keys
    var oauth_token = ""; //"insert here...";
    var oauth_token_secret = "; //"insert here...";
    var oauth_consumer_key = "";// = "insert here...";
    var oauth_consumer_secret = "";// = "insert here...";

    // oauth implementation details
    var oauth_version = "1.0";
    var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

    // unique request details
    var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
    var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow
        - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();


    // create oauth signature
    var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                    "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&q={6}";

    var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                oauth_consumer_key,
                                oauth_nonce,
                                oauth_signature_method,
                                oauth_timestamp,
                                oauth_token,
                                oauth_version,
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(q) //problem
                                );

    baseString = string.Concat("GET&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

    var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                            "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

    string oauth_signature;
    using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
    {
        oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
            hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
    }

    // create the request header
    var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
                       "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " +
                       "oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " +
                       "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

    var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                    );



    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

    // make the request
    var postBody = "q=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(q);//
    resource_url += "?" + postBody;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    myDiv.InnerHtml = objText;/**/
    string html = "";
    try
    {
        JArray jsonDat = JArray.Parse(objText);
        for (int x = 0; x < jsonDat.Count(); x++)
        {
            //html += jsonDat[x]["id"].ToString() + "<br/>";
            html += jsonDat[x]["text"].ToString() + "<br/>";
            // html += jsonDat[x]["name"].ToString() + "<br/>";
            html += jsonDat[x]["created_at"].ToString() + "<br/>";

        }
        myDiv.InnerHtml = html;
    }
    catch (Exception twit_error)
    {
        myDiv.InnerHtml = html + twit_error.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure this out. In the Oauth Signature, the base format has to be in alphabetical order and also be included in the postBody.

```
 var count = "5";                //*****************************************************************
    var exclude_replies = "true";  //******************************************************************
    var baseFormat = "count={7}&exclude_replies={8}&oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" + //************************
                    "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&q={6}";

    var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                oauth_consumer_key,
                                oauth_nonce,
                                oauth_signature_method,
                                oauth_timestamp,
                                oauth_token,
                                oauth_version,
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(q),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(count),          //*****************************************
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(exclude_replies)//*******************************************
                                );

    baseString = string.Concat("GET&", Uri.EscapeDataString(url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));//

    var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                            "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

    string oauth_signature;
    using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
    {
        oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
            hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
    }

    // create the request header
    var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
                       "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " +
                       "oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " +
                       "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

    var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                    );


    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

    // make the request
    var postBody = string.Format("q={0}&count={1}&exclude_replies={2}", Uri.EscapeDataString(q),Uri.EscapeDataString(count),Uri.EscapeDataString(exclude_replies));//***
    url += "?" + postBody;//
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);//
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    myDiv.InnerHtml = objText;/**/
    string html = "";
    try
    {
        JArray jsonDat = JArray.Parse(objText);
        for (int x = 0; x < jsonDat.Count(); x++)
        {
            //html += jsonDat[x]["id"].ToString() + "<br/>";
            html += jsonDat[x]["text"].ToString() + "<br/>";
            // html += jsonDat[x]["name"].ToString() + "<br/>";
           //html += jsonDat[x]["created_at"].ToString() + "<br/>";

        }
        myDiv.InnerHtml = html;
    }
    catch (Exception twit_error)
    {
        myDiv.InnerHtml = html + twit_error.ToString();
    }
}
```

}